# Entity Data Model Wizard Too Slow (SQL Database)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-5

Using:
visual studio 2012 Ultimate,
ADO Entity Framework 6,
Database: Sql express 2014 (installed on local PC),
Database tables count: 174 table.

I am trying to create database model using Entity Data Model Wizard but it takes about 8 hours to create the model(Dialog not responding).

I tried to reinstall visual studio & Entity Framework but the same problem. 
I need any ideas that can speed up database model creation.

[image: First image]
[image: Second image]
[image: Third image]

Comment: yes. i also tried to include only 20 tables but the same problem

Comment: And after those 8 hours, do you get a model? Or does it crash / get canceled?

Comment: After 8 hours i got the model created

Comment: No strange tables/columns in Tables node

Comment: this is the output of trying only 1 table :

Generated model file: Model1wr.edmx.
Loading metadata from the database took 00:00:02.1548860.
Generating the model took 00:00:39.8790941.
Added the connection string to the App.Config file.
Writing the .edmx file took 00:00:00.0005052.

Comment: 40 seconds seems long, do you have like hundreds of columns?

Comment: this table has only 11 columns

Comment: Update to the latest EF Tools (version 6.1.3) - it is a MSI installer, NOT a NuGet package

Comment: Same problem here, but well over 800 tables, even select just 2 tables is causing some extreme CPU (~50-75% usage and locking/hanging Visual Studio window.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700540/update-wizard-not-responding

Comment: This issue on the EF issue tracker: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/4

Comment: @ErikEJ I assume you are referring to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762 ? I haven't been able to find an equivalent for VS2015, the listed install states VS2012/13. According to my "programs and features" I already have `"Entity Framework 6.1.3 Tools for Visual Studio 2015 Update 1"` installed, and still have a problem after moving to full sql server from sql express.

Comment: @TimAbell You already have the latest build! I would recommend using the "EF Reverse POCO" template, it has knobs to avoid the issue with SQL metadata queries

Comment: I've updated sql server 2016 to [cumulative update 2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3182270) as well, still borked. Turned off sql proper and gone back to sql express so I can get some work done. Thanks for the suggestion of the tool, it's not a good moment on this project to be switching tooling, about to come to the end of the dev time.

Comment: 2018 still happens to be the same with latest version EF 6.1.3 SQL server 2017 and V Studio 2017

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Updating to Cumulative update package 5 for SQL Server 2014 fixes this issue, see https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/829555/visual-studio-freezes-during-entity-framework-db-reverse-engineering. The update is available at  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3011055

Comment: Service Pack 1 for SQL Server 2014 also fixes the issue.

Comment: [Update Center for Microsoft SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff803383.aspx) is useful for finding the latest update

Answer (score 17):

What worked for me is I changed my database compatibility back to 2012 before updating the model.

In SQL Management Studio, right-click on Database.

Properties-> Options -> Compatibility Level -> SQL Server 2012 (110)

Comment: It took me 14 hours to import a model, this fix works like a charm. The answer works with visual studio 2015 also

Answer (score 4):

I updated to Cumulative update package 5 for SQL Server 2014 fixes but it doesn't work for me.Finally I solved this issue is update SQL Server 2014 service pack 1

http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=46694

Answer (score 0):

Building on what PretoriaCoder said
Using SQL Server 2016 SP1 and Visual Studio 2017 with Entity Framework 6.2.0

Connecting to a 'our' DB compatibility set to 130, can generate the data model OK
Connecting to a third party DB (set at 130) entity model generation fails.

Setting the compatibility of the DB to 110 (in SQL server) and the entity model gets generated.