# Screen Getting Freeze When Updating Or Adding Tables To The Entity Framework Using The Wizard

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I'm using the Entity Framework and somehow it has started to get really slow when I'm trying to add or update the model.

Everything was working fine until someone execute some scripts to create some tables, and the scripts looks ok (she deleted it so i can't post it).

We have deleted those Tables and the problem is still there, and of course we don't have a back up.

If I click on the finish button the screen freeze but like in 20 minutes or more it finish correctly.

Does some one have had the similar problem in the past and give me some clue?

I can't see any log or any error in the screen so I'm super lost and looking for any idea.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

**EDIT:**

I'm Using Visual Studio 2012 and SQL Server 2014

This guy is having the same problem

http://forums.asp.net/t/1911430.aspx?update+model+in+entity+framework+consumes+more+time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution:

It looks like is a problem with SQL 2014, you have to install this:

[Hot fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3011055)

If you are curious here is more information:

[Microsoft Forum](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/829555/visual-studio-freezes-during-entity-framework-db-reverse-engineering)

[Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30053661/entity-data-model-wizard-too-slow-sql-database)

Comment: Thank you for posting your findings. I was experiencing similar issues and this helped out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server may be holding the process, Try [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/visual-studio-entity-data-model-wizard-not-responding)

```
ALTER DATABASE [YOUR_DB_NAME]
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110;
GO
```