# Alternate way to get to "Update model from Database" and Model Browser without opening up edmx file using ADO.NET Entity Model Designer?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, ado.net, edmx-designer

The edmx file is taking a long time to load.  It's taken 3.5 minutes.  That is one problem.

I open up the edmx file using ADO.NET Entity Model Designer only to get to "Update model from Database" and also Model Browser. Is there a way to get to them without having to open up edmx?  I don't need see the database diagram at all.  I do however need to see the Model Browser to select an entity to delete from time to time.

Comment: first, I will recommend that you use the latest version of vs2019 to generate the edmx file. Also, you can look at the link [Generating Entity Framework model takes too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48388870/generating-entity-framework-model-takes-too-long)to know the similar issue.

Comment: second, based on my research, it seems that we may not avoid opening the edmx file to update model from database.